# How to manage my standalone postgres with Heroku CLI

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

I am a Heroku newbie. What I did is to create several Production tier databases. Then I tried the Heroku toolbelt. Seems it has lots of useful commands I believe I can use to manage and monitor my databases. Additionally I created one app. Seems this is important in order to be able to execute commands like :

```
heroku pg:info
```

The problem here is that I can work only with the database (basic one) associated with my app.
What should I do to be able to monitor and work with my production databases using the Heroku toolbelt CLI?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I want to add that I refereed to : https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#connection-permissions and I have POSTGRES installed locally so the native libs should be available.

Comment: What I am trying is : D:\workspace_sts\HerokuSampleApp>heroku pg:psql
 !    Unknown database. Valid options are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL Seems I am missing the [] brackets for the DB URL 
D:\workspace_sts\HerokuSampleApp>heroku pg:psql postgres://XXXXXXXXX:pcb24a2s4fd2327p9qdhq4pelv5@<AMAZON_IP>:<PORT>/d
5vj802XXXXXXX
 !    Unknown database: postgres://XXXXXXXXX:pcb24a2s4fd2327p9qdhq4pelv5@<AMAZON_IP>:<PORT>/d5vj802XXXXXXX. Valid opt
ions are: HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_GRAY_URL

Comment: I found that I am missing [] brackets for my DB URL. Nevertheless I have: D:\workspace_sts\HerokuSampleApp>heroku pg:psql [postgres://ucfjXXXXXb2:pcbXXXXq4pelv5@ec2-23-21-122-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:XXXX/d5vjXXXXXX1d]
 !    Heroku client internal error.
    Error:       empty range in char class: /[postgres:\/\/ucXXXXX2:pcb24aXXXXXXX5@ec2-23-21-122-219.compute-1.amazonaws.com:6022\/d5vj80XXXXX]/i (RegexpError)
    Backtrace:   C:/Program Files (x86)/Heroku/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:108:in `match_attachments_by_name' Version:     heroku/toolbelt/2.34.0 (i386-mingw32)ruby/1.9.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Databases created on postgres.heroku.com do not grant CLI access. If you want CLI access, you can create Heroku apps with no running dynos and just attach database plans to them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ctshryock! I added some more details in my own answer.

Answer (score 1):

First Heroku Postgres standalone databases actually have a behind the scenes app created for them, because of this I'd actually encourage you to just create a fake application to put in front of your database. This will allow you the use of the tool belt to work with your database, which gives you some additional tools. The pg commands in the tool belt will give you basic insight into your database. Beyond that there is a plugin that you can use that will tell you things such as cache hit rate and index hit rate (https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras/). I'd also encourage the use of Postgres 9.2, you can specify the version when provisioning at the command line, this gives you pg_stat_statements which will also give you further insight (http://craigkerstiens.com/2013/01/10/more-on-postgres-performance/).